# How to store data permanently which is posted to an API server using axios library in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a **redux-form** which is used to receive data from users and store it to an API.My redux-form is as shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createPosts } from '../actions/posts_action';

const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1'); //For generating unique id for each post

class CreatePost extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectValue : ''
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.renderCategory = this.renderCategory.bind(this);
}

  renderField(field) {
      return(
        <div className="title-design">
            <label className="label-design"> {field.label} </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="title-input"
              {...field.input}
            />
            <div className="text-help  has-danger">
              {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
            </div>
      </div>
      );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const value=e.target.value;
    this.props.change("categories",value);
    this.setState({selectValue: value}, () => {
      console.log(value)
    });
  }

  renderCategory(field) {
    return(
      <div className="title-design">
        <label className="label-design">{field.label} </label>
          <Field name="category" className="title-input" component="select">
            <option></option>
            <option value="react">React</option>
            <option value="redux">Redux</option>
            <option value="udacity">Udacity</option>
          </Field>

          <div className="text-help has-danger">
            {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

    onSubmit(values) {

          this.props.createPosts(values, () => {
            uuidv1();
            console.log(uuidv1());
          this.props.history.push('/');
      });
    }



    render() {
      const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field
            label="Title for Post"
            name="title"
            component={this.renderField}
          />

          <Field
            label="Post Content"
            name="body"
            component={this.renderField}
          />

          <Field
            label="Category"
            name="category"
            component={this.renderCategory}
            />



          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          <Link  to="/">
            <button className="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
          </Link>
        </form>
      );
    }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {} ;

  if (!values.title) {
      errors.title = "Enter a title";
  }

  if (!values.body) {
    errors.body = "Enter some content";
    }

  if(!values.category) {
    errors.category = "Please select a category";
  }

  return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate : validate,          //validate
  form : 'CreatePostForm'
})(
  connect(null,{ createPosts })(CreatePost)
);
```

**Action creator** for creating the post:

```
//Action Creator for creating posts
export function createPosts(values, callback) {

  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post(`${API}/posts`,values,{headers})
      .then((data) => {
        callback();
        console.log(data)
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_POST,
        payload: data
      })
    })
  }
}
```

**Reducer** for the posts is:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_POST, CREATE_POST } from '../actions/posts_action';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POST:
      return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};

    case FETCH_POSTS:
     return {posts: { ...state.posts, ...action.payload }};

    case CREATE_POST:
      return {posts: { ...state, ...action.payload}};

     default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

So,now what happens is when I try to post data to the server,I am able to see the data set if I console.log, but if I want to add a second set of data to the API,then the first set of data is deleted and only the second set remains.So,how to save the records for each set of data to the API?

**Edit 1:**

My index.js file with all the reducers is:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import PostReducer from './PostsReducer';
import { reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
import CategoriesReducer from './CategoriesReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: PostReducer,
    categories: CategoriesReducer,
    form : formReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**EDIT 2:** My updated Reducer:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_POST, CREATE_POST } from '../actions/posts_action';

export default function(state = {posts: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POST:
      return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};

    case FETCH_POSTS:
     return {posts: { ...state.posts, ...action.payload }};

    case CREATE_POST:
      return {...state, posts: [...posts, ...action.payload]};

     default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

**Edit 3:** Screenshot of "data" content

[image: post_data]

Answer (score 0):

First set your `posts` default value in your default state, so later we can use the spread operator on the array to generate the mutation.

```
export default function(state = { posts: [] }, action) {
  ...
}
```

Then, currently you are replacing your posts slice of the redux store with the payload:

```
case CREATE_POST:
  {posts: { ...state, ...action.payload}};
```

The following happens in your store:

```
{
  posts: {
    posts: action.payload
  },
  categories,
  form
}
```

You should instead just add the new post:

```
case CREATE_POST:
  {...state, posts: [...state.posts, action.payload]};
```

The following happens in your store:

```
{
  posts: {
    posts: [post1, post2, ... , action.payload]
  },
  categories,
  form
}
```

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get exactly what you said in the first point.I need to set the default state in my main reducer file where all the reducers are combined together right?If so,I have attached my index file above in an edit.Could you please explain a bit how to do that,I mean where do I set the default state.Sorry,I am new to redux,so I am totally confused.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more specific to your redux store based on your rootReducer.

Comment: I tried it the way you mentioned but I got an error which says : "'posts' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: At what point you get that error? Did you set the default state (state = { posts: [] })?

Comment: I get the error here:   return {...state, posts: [...posts, ...action.payload]};    And yes,I did set the default state as (state = { posts: [] })

Comment: I have added my updated reducer file in an edit above.Can you please have a look at it .

Comment: It should be {...state, posts: [...state.posts, action.payload]}. I was missing the state reference in state.posts and not spread operator for the payload.

Comment: It works now,but I still face the issue that I mentioned earlier,i.e. if a second set of data is entered,the first set of data gets removed and only the second set remains.

Comment: Can you share the content of `data` from your API call?

Comment: I have added the  screenshot in an edit above of the data which I tried to console.log.Can you please have a look at it one.

Comment: My understanding was that every time you create a post, the new post was replacing your previous post in redux. And I can guarantee that your original CREATE_POST had a flaw in the mutation and  {...state, posts: [...state.posts, action.payload]}.  Now you need to elaborate more what actions are triggered between the first CREATE_POST and the second. Also, how are you accessing your redux data? I noticed that FETCH_POST stores post by ID and the other ones mutate the posts array. It could be the case that this discrepancy is causing you trouble, e.g. access by id vs access by index.

Comment: I have my complete project in a github repo.The link is: https://github.com/PranamiBG/Readable-project/tree/master/src  . Would you mind taking a look at it ,so that you will be able to view all the files .

Comment: This line https://github.com/PranamiBG/Readable-project/blob/d49fbb4297b189b47b4e6430238d9c4a824e9d10/src/reducers/PostsReducer.js#L17 should be `return {...state, posts: [...state.posts, action.payload]};`

Comment: On a side note, when you fetch a single post through your FETCH_POST, you duplicate data because you store those by ID. You end up having posts by ID and then a list of post in an array. That's an anti-pattern that can lead to discrepancy in the data. Read https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Comment: okay,so is my issue causing because of the way I am storing the data or there may be some other reason?Also,i changed the switch case in reducer as you mentioned,but still the same issue.

Comment: Let’s see what it is. I have two questions. First, your PostsIndex component, where you navigate there after creating a new post, expects state.posts.posts to be an object and your FETCH_POSTS defines one from the payload. Can your share that payload too? Second question, the payload of CREAT_POST that you previously shared, does not have an id. Why? In your code you make references to a post.id